# Mapping the first 4 characters and last 4 characters in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i was wondering if i could get some help with a problem i have encounter. To summerise, im taking the last 4 digits of a serial number and appling a meter model and manufacturer code to it.

In this example, all G4F0 meters are manufactured by FLN and if the last 4 digits are between 2000-2999 they are classed as meter model: G4SZV-2 and if they end between 1000-1999 the meter model: G4SZV-1.

However my issue is when introducing other meter types. For instance the last two serial numbers are returning as G4SZV-1 and G4SZV-2. To get around this I was wondering if there is a way to map the last 4 strings and first 4 and map based on that? This would be better with mapping models and manufactures to the correct serial number!

EXAMPLE:

```
  gas_data["New Meter Model"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"2061": "G470"})
  gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"2061": "LPG"})
  gas_data["New Meter Model"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"1914": "BK-G4E"})
  gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"1914": "HWL"})
```

----Current code----

```
import pandas as pd

gas_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\test.csv')
 
    new_gas_data["New Meter Model"] = new_gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map(
            {str(i): f"G4SZV-{str(i)[0]}" for i in range(1000, 3000)})

    new_gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = new_gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map(
        {str(d): f"FLN" for d in range(1000, 3000)})
```

----Current Output----

| New Serial Number | New Meter Model | New Meter Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G4F01268172000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01248692000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01274872000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01274632000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4K00000011914 | G4SZV-1 | FLN |
| E6S15543432061 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |

----Desired outcome----

| New Serial Number | New Meter Model | New Meter Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G4F01268172000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01248692000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01274872000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4F01274632000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |
| G4K00000011914 | BK-G4E | HWL |
| E6S15543432061 | G470 | LPG |

----test csv----
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxLO7c2veCJOHp7Uw_3ZuUtYUvvMHtelEE-UW9QpY9g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is, I think, a nice and quite robust solution.
First, let's define some mapping as dictionaries:

```
manufacturers = {'G4F0': 'FLN', 'G4K0': 'HWL', 'E6S1': 'LPG'}

meter_models  = {'G4F0': {'1': 'G4SZV-1', '2': 'G4SZV-2'},
                 'G4K0': {'': 'BK-G4E'},
                 'E6S1': {'': 'G470'},
                 }
```

`manufacturers` will match the first four characters to a manufacturer and `meter_models` will match for each first four characters the model name based on the beginning of the last four character. This means that '1' will match all models for which the last four characters start with '1', '' will match everything.

Then craft a custom function to do the mapping and apply it on the meter serial number:

```
def map_manufacturer_model(s):
    s = str(s)
    model = 'unknown'
    try:
        manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
        for k,m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
            if s[-4:].startswith(k):
                model = m
                break
    except KeyError:
        manufacturer = 'unknown'
    
    return pd.Series({'New Meter Manufacturer': manufacturer,
                      'New Meter Model': model
                     })

gas_data['New Serial Number'].apply(map_manufacturer_model)
```

output:

```
  New Meter Manufacturer New Meter Model
0                    FLN         G4SZV-2
1                    FLN         G4SZV-2
2                    FLN         G4SZV-2
3                    FLN         G4SZV-2
4                    HWL          BK-G4E
5                    LPG            G470
```

and of course, if you want to insert the columns in the original dataframe:

```
df[['New Meter Manufacturer', 'New Meter Model']] = gas_data['New Serial Number'].apply(map_manufacturer_model)
```

Comment: This makes sense to me! However when im trying to implement the solution im getting the error:

 line 26, in map_manufacturer_model manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This means you have a number in the 'New Serial Number' column, you can convert it first to string. I also updated the answer to add a failsafe.

Comment: for some of the data there is blank fields too,     manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
KeyError: 'nan', How do i get around Nan's?

Comment: You keep changing the question here ;) Try the updated code. Then I am sure you can figure out eventual other cases by yourself. Remember, SO is to help you out with solving a unitary problem, not to develop you a complete application ;)

Comment: Don't hesitate to open a new question if needed! It's always better to have questions revolving around a single problem.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about `map` etc. but maybe you could work with a function like this...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

print(df, '\n\n')

''' Shows:

  New Serial Number New Meter Model New Meter Manufacturer
0    G4F01268172000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
1    G4F01248692000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
2    G4F01274872000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
3    G4F01274632000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
4    G4K00000011914         G4SZV-1                    FLN
5    E6S15543432061         G4SZV-2                    FLN

'''

def mapValues(x):
    start = x['New Serial Number'][:4]
    end = int(x['New Serial Number'][-4:])
    if start == 'G4F0' and (2000 <= end <= 2999):
        return ['G4SZV-2', 'FLN']
    elif start == 'G4F0' and (1000 <= end <= 1999):
        return ['G4SZV-1', 'FLN']
    elif start != 'G4F0' and (2000 <= end <= 2999):
        return ['G470', 'LPG']
    elif start != 'G4F0' and (1000 <= end <= 1999):
        return ['BK-G4E', 'HWL']
    else:
        return ['unknown', 'unknown']

df[['New Meter Model 2','New Meter Manufacturer 2']] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(list(mapValues(row))), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    New Serial Number   New Meter Model     New Meter Manufacturer  New Meter Model 2   New Meter Manufacturer 2
0   G4F01268172000      G4SZV-2             FLN                     G4SZV-2             FLN
1   G4F01248692000      G4SZV-2             FLN                     G4SZV-2             FLN
2   G4F01274872000      G4SZV-2             FLN                     G4SZV-2             FLN
3   G4F01274632000      G4SZV-2             FLN                     G4SZV-2             FLN
4   G4K00000011914      G4SZV-1             FLN                     BK-G4E              HWL
5   E6S15543432061      G4SZV-2             FLN                     G470                LPG
```

**Note:** You could alternatively overwrite the existing columns by changing the second to last line to `df[['New Meter Model','New Meter Manufacturer']] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(list(mapValues(row))), axis=1)`  (same names are the existing columns).

---

**Update:**

Modified the code above so if a match isn't found it returns `unknown`.  This could be changed if required and in any case filtered on to correct for future runs etc.  Example output in the case of an unknown:

```
New Serial Number   New Meter Model New Meter Manufacturer  New Meter Model 2   New Meter Manufacturer 2
6   1010101010101   G4SZV-2         FLN                     unknown             unknown
```

Comment: This also makes sense but i keep getting the error float is not subscriptable for this solution too

Comment: Updated the code with `else: return ['unknown', 'unknown']` to catch if it doesn't match.  Depending on what you wanted to do you could see what is returned as unknown by filtering and add to the `elif` options to return what you require.